# I can't get my VBA loop to work through multiple sheets. It does the active sheet only

Tags: excel, vba, foreach

Code below - it works well for the active sheet but then doesn't do anything further, I've tried a couple of methods online but I don't understand why it won't loop through my other sheets. Any help greatly appreciated,

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Loop()
    'Loop through each worksheet in a workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets    
        'What we gonna do
        Dim WSR As Range
        Set WSR = Range("A4:GG100")

        Dim Test_Criteria As String
        Test_Criteria = Range("a1")

        On Error Resume Next
        WSR.ShowAllData
        On Error GoTo 0
  
        WSR.Range("a4:gg1000").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>" & Test_Criteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues
  
        '2. Delete Rows
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        WSR.Range("a2:gg1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set WSR = ws.Range("A4:GG100")`, `Test_Criteria = ws.Range("a1")`. `If ws.AutoFilerMode Then ws.ShowAllData`.

Comment: Also `WSR.Range("a4:gg1000").AutoFilter` --> `WSR.AutoFilter`. and `WSR.Range("a2:gg1000").SpecialCells` --> `WSR.SpecialCells`. `WSR` is a `Range`.

Comment: `WSR.ShowAllData` --> `ws.ShowAllData`.

Comment: And `If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` surely is meant to be `if ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData`

Comment: @JNevill Should probably be `ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` too